# Why do my tooltips not show on my main form?

Tags: c#, winforms, tooltip

I have two forms. The first form "Main" has 2 buttons and a link label that I have set up tool tips for. My second form "settingsForm" has several tool tips as well. The tooltips all work correctly on the SettingsForm, however none work on the Main form. The tooltips for both forms are established within the same method which resides in the Main forms code. Here is how they are called:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
FormSettings formSettings = new FormSettings();
ToolTip toolTip1 = new ToolTip();

public Form1()
{

InitializeComponent();

//does not work
toolTip1.SetToolTip(this.btnExit, "Shutdown the program");   
//does work
toolTip1.SetToolTip(formSettings.btnSave, "Save the programs settings");
}
```

It also fails to work properly if I call it without the "this"

```
//does not work
toolTip1.SetToolTip(btnExit, "Shutdown the program");
```

Am I just calling the main form items incorrectly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A tooltip control has to be associated with a single form.

The behavior of the tooltip control is that it will be "assigned" to the form associated with the last control that you call SetToolTip on. In your example, if you switch the order of the SetToolTips, they will be shown for the main form and not the settings form.

You need to add and use tooltip controls separately for each form.

Comment: I'm confused then. Why can I add the tool tips to my settingsform from my main forms code, but not add tool tips to the main form itself from the main form. It seems to go in the opposite direction of what your saying.

Comment: which form is `toolTip1`'s parent form, you will need to add a seperate toolTip control to each form.

Comment: toolTip1's parent form is Main form. I understand what both comments are saying, however I'm not having an issue with adding tips to a secondary form, I can't seem to add them to my main form, despite my main form being the class that creates toolTip1.

Comment: @FuzzEvans: I have updated the answer to show what is happening. Basically, the last call to SetToolTip locks the tooltip control to the form that control lives on.

Comment: Thanks for the additional info. Here's a new strange thing though. I went and added the tooltips within the settingsForm and only had it handle those tooltips which were for the settingsForm, I left the original ones on the mainform as it was, so how they were and not working, but it works now? So based on your information above, since the last tooltip established is on the settingsForm it should not have any working on the main form, yet they do now?

Comment: @FuzzEvans: Did you add a new tooltip control to the settings form? If so, that is what solved your problem. It's only a problem if you try to use a tooltip control on one form in a different form.

Comment: I added a tooltip within the second forms code that is specifically only for those items that are in that form, however I did not change the original code at all. I don't understand why adding the tool tip to the settings form code in addition to the main form solved the problem?

Comment: It could be that once the control was registered on the second form, the attempt to register the second form's control on the first form failed or the tooltip control on the first form looked to see if there was a tooltip control in the second form before setting the tooltip and bailed since it found one. Regardless, the upshot is that you should always have 1 tooltip control per form and that control should only service controls on that form.